How to silence “unknown dhcp option value 0x7d” in OPNSense
I keep getting the following log message whenever the DNS lease on my external interface is renewed:

Error:dhclient:unknown dhcp option value 0x7d

Since the lifetime my ISP has configured for their DNS leases is such that the lease gets renewed every 15 minutes, this error appears every 15 minutes, cluttering my log.
DHCP option value 0x7d is some vendor-specific nonstandard option which is not really relevant to OPNsense and thus would be safe to ignore.
Maybe the clean way to fix this would be to get my ISP to fix this (but this isn’t likely to happen). On the other hand, the clean way to handle extensible data formats is to simply ignore options/tags/format extensions which the parser does not understand – occurrence of an unknown option would at most trigger a debug message, but not an error.
Is there any way to suppress this? Or should I file a bug (with OPNsense? Or somewhere else – where?)
Update: I’ve filed a bug report with FreeBSD at https://bugs.freebsd.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=281361. Let’s see...

My guess is that it is logged as an error because the client didn't request it – DHCP already has a mechanism for negotiating supported options... so although there indeed may be use cases for the server sending all kinds of options, it ought to only send them if the client indicates it understands and wants that option, otherwise sending it is just pointless. That may be why dhclient (FreeBSD's version at least) chose to be loud about it.
